# уникальный идентификатор

Tags: java

создал класс с выводом данных о пользователе. как мне сделать так, чтобы идентификатор являлся уникальным и работал только на положительные числа, а на отрицательные программа переставала бы работать?

public class User {

```
int id;
String login;
String password;

public User(int id, String login, String password){
    this.id = id;
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

public class MainUser {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   User[] u = new User[2];
   u[0] = new User(1, "shiva", "ppp");
   u[1] = new User(2, "papa", "gggg");
    for (int i = 0; i < u.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("id = " + u[i].id + ";" + " login = " + u[i].login + ";" + " password = " + u[i].password);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class IdGenerator {
    private static int id = 0;
    
    public static int generate(){
       return id++;
    }
    
}
    
    ...
public class User {
    
    private id = IdGenerator.generate();
    ....
```

Comment: Это, конечно, если все это не имеет хранимого состояния, то есть, обнуляется каждый раз при запуске программы

Comment: И еще это не будет работать, если `generate` вызывается из нескольких потоков.

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko, нужно добавить блок синхронизации, чтобы правильно работало в нескольких потоках :)

Comment: @gil9red это не та задача в которой надо думать о синхронизации)) Но да, в более серьезном примере надо добавить